# Best web crawlers for commercial purpose?

Tags: web-crawler, nutch

I am developing a system that crawls tens of millions of webpages, which will go on live.
I would rather not develop a crawler from scratch.

Which open-source web crawlers fit the following criteria:

- can be customized
- highly scalable
- crawls ajax websites easily
- crawls intelligently
- obeys politeness

In case I have missed any, please evaluate other criteria that you think are important.

I have a list of the following open-source crawlers. Do they posses the features mentioned above?

1. Scrapy
2. Mechanize
3. Nutch
4. Heritrix
5. flax
6. httrack
7. Spidher
8. Searcharoo

Comment: +1 Wana do something like this....Keen to know response to this query of yours...

Comment: [Stack Overflow doesn't provide product or service recommendations](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128562/171237).

Comment: if by providing the service recommendation solves one's doubt/query, then why not respond to it!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I've been working with nutch for awhile now and it seems like it would fit this criteria pretty well. Plugin systems allow you to crawl new materials and easy deployment. One thing I had difficulty with was getting it to use multiple proxies but overall it is very customizable.